# blogdown not following git ignore

Tags: git, blogdown

I am running blogdown and having an issue with my gitignore file not actually ignoring files in the public folder.  I have the following .gitignore file in the main project directory in Rstudio:

```
.Rproj.user
.Rhistory
.RData
.Ruserdata
Thumbs.db
public
```

However, each time I run serve_site or hugo_build, my Git window gets full of all the updated files in public.  I have tried changing public to /public or /public/ but it does not seem to fix the problem.  Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the ignore rule should be

```
public/
```

(the trailing `/` at the end is important)

Second, if public was already tracked before, the rule won't apply.

Try:

```
git rm -r --cached public/
```

Then see if your "Git window" is still full.

Comment: without the trailing slash should be fine too.  It's a little over-greedy as it also matches files and symlinks -- but it should do the job for matching the directory in this case.

Comment: @AnthonySottile re-reading https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format, I agree with you, but I always prefer to be specific in this case. I just want the folder public to be ignored in my Hugo projects.

Comment: Oh for sure, totally agree it _should_ be that in this case, but it isn't what's causing the OP's problem :)

Comment: @AnthonySottile no, the second part of my answer addresses the possible root cause of the issue.